# Filtro em lista com flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Preciso fazer o filtro em uma lista tipo JSON com base em sua ID, estou carregando os dados da lista e depois tendo fazer o filtro com where, porém ela retorna vazia mesmo sua ID existindo.

A lista está assim:

```
class Bancos {
  static List<Map> getBancos() {
    List<Map> _myBankJSON = [
      {"id": '1',  "name": "Abc Brasil","image": "assets/bancosimg/abcbrasil.png"},
      {"id": '2',  "name": "Abn Amro", "image": "assets/bancosimg/abnamro.png"},
  
    ];
    return _myBankJSON;
  }
}
```

e o fitro que estou tentando fazer:

```
class __BancoFiltradoState extends State<_BancoFiltrado> {
  List<Map> _dadosBanco;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _dadosBanco = Bancos.getBancos();
   var teste = _dadosBanco.where((element) => element['id'] == 1);
    print(teste.toList());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
    );
  }
}
```

Como posso fazer esse filtro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você está comparando um `int` com `String` aqui:

```dart
_dadosBanco.where((element) => element['id'] == 1);
```

Uma vez que o elemento é um `Map<String, String>`.
Exemplo comparando corretamente com `String`:

```dart
void main() {
  final list = <Map>[
      {"id": '1',  "name": "Abc Brasil","image": "assets/bancosimg/abcbrasil.png"},
      {"id": '2',  "name": "Abn Amro", "image": "assets/bancosimg/abnamro.png"},
    ];

  print(list.where((e) => e['id'] == 1));
  print(list.where((e) => e['id'] == '1'));
}
```

O segundo `where` vai imprimir o elemento encontrado. Exemplo rodando no [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/980d20a60e002849de8500bd84fc2b0b).